# Under what conditions is the word Britisher offensive?

Tags: etymology, pejorative-language, offensive-language, subcontinental-english

I have often heard individuals from the [Indian subcontinent refer to the pre-independance British colonial rulers as "Britishers."](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_names_for_the_British#Britisher) I have never heard the word in another context.

It seems that today, to call [someone from the UK a Britisher might be offensive](https://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/169619-British-or-Britisher). Is this true?

Is it offensive to refer to the colonial rulers as Britishers?

More importantly, what is the etymology of this name?

Comment: All I can tell you is this: "*noun, informal* (in North America and old-fashioned British English) a native or inhabitant of Britain." –Google. Anything and everything else would be an opinion, IMO ;) - And some other stuff easily found on Wiktionary: "Its use was once considered pejorative, but is now mostly considered jocular."

Comment: “You can please some of the people all of the time, you can please all of the people some of the time, but you can't please all of the people all of the time.” VTC: POB.

Comment: I would love to know the etymology. The term was spoken by German soldiers in British (English language) WWI and WWII films - "Das is Britisher". The morphology sounds Dutch, though. Great question!

Comment: I can tell you that as a "Brit" I don't find it offensive in the least! I can't recall any pejorative use from a lifetime of watching movies and reading this and that, etc.

Comment: @MickSharpe  For you, Tommy, zee vaw is over!

Comment: @PeterPoint - "Don't tell him, Pike."

Comment: @MickSharpe You've made me all misty-eyed. One of the Beeb's best sitcoms.

Comment: Perhaps the -er ending is related to the Germanic -er ending meaning 'of a given place' e.g. *Berliner*

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey  Quite so! As in JFK's expression of solidarity with the divided city of Berlin when he uttered the phrase, "Ich bin ein Berliner", during his visit to West Berlin in 1963. By adding the article "ein" before "Berliner', he was  perfectly well understood by the enormous crowd as regsitering solidarity with the city's denizens, east and west. To say, "Ich bin Berliner", without the word "ein", would have suggested being born in Berlin (Wikipedia). JFK's detractors suggested that what he actually said in German meant, "I am a jelly doughnut". Wikipedia dispels this, however.

Comment: If we can cobble all this together, we'll have a good answer. Any volunteers?

Comment: While *Britisher* is not offensive, most people I know in Britain take *Brit* as being offensive.

Comment: @Chenmunka, do you have any reference for that? It's a rather sweeping claim; personally, as a **Brit** I find it merely descriptive and it holds no pejorative connotations

Comment: Maybe *most* is too strong.  Also, nowadays it has become common usage.  However, there are plenty of older people who dislike the term intensely.  Personall, I have come to accept it.

Comment: Proud to be a Brit and a Taffy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Wiktionary:

> Britisher is mainly used in the Indian subcontinent, having become popular there during the British Raj. *Its use was once considered pejorative, but is now mostly considered jocular.*

This trend of once-offensiveness seems to stem from Britain's colonisation of a sizeable chunk of the world; basically we sailed up to countries and 'claimed' them for Her Majesty and then proceeded to massacre most of the native peoples and to ship in our own population.

In all of this, you had the native people, who tended not to like the invaders, who referred to the British by the common epithet **Britisher**. Originally not pejorative (indeed used as an autonym) it quickly became so when used by the oppressed.

This was used pejoratively for another 90-odd years, by which time we get to the stage of Britain giving back her colonies, often unceremoniously. By then, negative feeling towards the '*Britishers*' was at an all time high, and, as many older people will remember, *Britisher* was definitely pejorative.

In the following 70 years until now, it has fallen out of use worldwide with a few older people and those from ex-colonial countries still using it.

cf. [Ngrams of Britisher](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Britisher&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CBritisher%3B%2Cc0)